# Does FTP server supports UTF-16 encoding?

Tags: ftp, encoding, utf-8

I am checking my application for different encoding techniques. In one such use case related to the FTP server, I do not see anything related to UTF-16. This means I can able login to the FTP server if it has UTF-8 and if I change that to UTF-16 I could not able to log in to the FTP server. I have executed "FEAT" from my client on that server, i do not see UTF-16 in the response. Does this mean my FTP server does not support it?

I can enable UTF-8 on the FTP server by executing the command `OPTS UTF8 ON`. Is there any such command where I can enable UTF-16 on the FTP server or it doesn't support UTF-16 ??

Below is the response of `FEAT` command

```
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Features:
Response:    MDTM
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    SIZE
Response:    MLST type*;size*;modify*;perm*;
Response:    MLSD
Response:    AUTH SSL
Response:    AUTH TLS
Response:    PROT
Response:    PBSZ
Response:    **UTF8**
Response:    TVFS
Response:    EPSV
Response:    EPRT
Response:    MFMT
Response:   211 End
```

** NOTE: HTTP/HTTPS supports both UTF-8 and UTF-16 where I can log in

### Steps I have been tried before stepping into codng

1. FTP server is created locally with a directory
2. From FTP Client (FileZilla) connecting to FTP server

   - When I have charset as UTF-8, the connection is successful.
   - When I have charset as UTF-16, the connection is not successful
     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NySA0.png) and below is the response

   **Below is the log Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message... Response: ㈲ⴰ楆敬楚汬⁡敓癲牥ㄠ㐮ㄮ Error: Could not connect to server Status: Waiting to retry... Status: Resolving address of localhost Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:21... Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message... Response: ㈲ⴰ楆敬楚汬⁡敓癲牥ㄠ㐮ㄮ Error: Could not connect to server**

Comment: Is there a need for UTF-16, or are you only asking out of curiosity?

Comment: There is a need in our application. We are already supporting UTF8 for FTP . And UTF8 and UTF16 both are working when using with HTTP/HTTPS. Now enabling UTF16 is not successful while logging in to the FTP server

Comment: It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `'㈲ⴰ楆敬楚汬⁡敓癲牥ㄠ㐮'.encode( 'utf-16-le').decode( 'utf-8')` returns `'220-FileZilla Server 1.4'`…

Answer (score 2):

FTP does not support UTF-16. It is a text-based protocol which uses ASCII for commands and responses; it is able to support UTF-8 only because the latter is a superset of ASCII (e.g. commands like `FEAT` are encoded exactly the same way in both). The same applies to older encodings such as ISO-8859, but *does not* apply to UTF-16 – the initial server greeting (which is always in ASCII) will not be understood by a client expecting UTF-16, and commands sent as UTF-16 will not be understood by the server.

Usually however there is no practical need to support both encodings – both UTF-8 and UTF-16 are just different representations of the same Unicode codepoints; any filename that can be encoded UTF-16 can also be encoded as UTF-8 and vice versa. For example, even though Windows internally uses UTF-16 for file names, Windows FTP servers still use UTF-8 and just convert between the two as needed.

Comment: it helped for me to understand. Now i can see that UTF-8 is the superset of ASCII, if any text is encoded with ASCII or UTF-8, will be supported/read using the UTF-8. And also UTF-16 is incompatible with ASCII. If any data is encoded with UTF-16 the same has to be read using only UTF-16. I tried with FTP, SFTP it is not working for me if i encode using UTF-16